# react: combining 2 functions

Tags: function, reactjs

I have 2 functions:

```
handleValue1(event) {
  this.setState({number1: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)});
}

handleValue2(event) {
  this.setState({number2: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)});
}

...

onChange={this.handleValue1.bind(this)}
onChange={this.handleValue2.bind(this)}
```

I want to combine these 2 functions to 1.
I was try:

```
handleValue(event, name) {
  this.setState({name: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)});
}

...

input onChange={this.handleValue.bind(this, "number1")}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the name dynamically, you will need to use the *bracket* syntax:

```
var obj = {};
obj[name] = value;
```

So, your method would become:

```
handleValue(event, name) {
    var newState = {};
    newState[name] = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Otherwise, you are asking for an object literal with a property named `name`.

Comment: Babel would come in handy here with enhanced object literals. https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals